# Error when creating Usage Plan using AWS CLI for a specific Stage in API Gateway

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, aws-cli

I want to create a usage plan for an associated API stage. I am using the following command right now:

```
aws apigateway create-usage-plan --name "New Usage Plan1"  --api-stages  '[{ "apiId": "abcde12345", "stage":"test-stage", "throttle": {"Test from CLI": { "burstLimit": 200, "rateLimit": 100}}}]' --throttle burstLimit=200,rateLimit=100 --quota limit=500,offset=0,period=MONTH
```

where `abcde12345` is my Rest API ID, `test-stage` is the stage I want it to be associated with, `Test from CLI` is the API Key I successfully created.

I get the following error:

```
An error occurred (BadRequestException) when calling the CreateUsagePlan operation: Invalid method {resourcePath: Test from CLI,method: } specified
```

I tried replacing the Key `Test from CLI` with the ID of the API Key `abc123` but that throws the same error as well:

```
An error occurred (BadRequestException) when calling the CreateUsagePlan operation: Invalid method {resourcePath: abc123,method: } specified
```

I looked at [this](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/apigateway/create-usage-plan.html) to create this usage plan. Where am I going wrong in this command?

Comment: `Test from CLI`  is not a valid method name. What exactly do you want to accomplish and do with `Test from CLI`?

Comment: According to the docs linked above, the format when using a stage should be `apiId=string,stage=string,throttle={KeyName1={burstLimit=integer,rateLimit=double}` . Here `Test from CLI` is the name of my API Key

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Test from CLI is the name of my API Key

This is not what `KeyName1` referers to. This is a key name representing your method in your API, e.g. `/pets/GET` in the following default example :

```
    "apiStages": [
        {
            "apiId": "ym7ggv1kh6",
            "stage": "test",
            "throttle": {
                "/pets/GET": {
                    "burstLimit": 33,
                    "rateLimit": 33.0
                }
            }
        }
    ],
```

Comment: I am using a POST method in my API. So when running the command now: `aws apigateway create-usage-plan --name "New Usage Plan1"  --api-stages  '[{ "apiId": "abcde12345", "stage":"test-stage", "throttle": {"POST": { "burstLimit": 200, "rateLimit": 100}}}]' --throttle burstLimit=200,rateLimit=100 --quota limit=500,offset=0,period=MONTH` it gives a `no matches found: [apiId:abcde12345]` This is the REST API ID for my API. In your example is the `"apiId":"ym7ggv1kh6"` the REST API ID?

Comment: @Navidk I do not know what methods do you have in your code. You haven't provided any information about them. Only you know what methods you have. Clearly the method you gave it the command does not exist.

Comment: The method is "POST /target" which makes the command `aws apigateway create-usage-plan --name "New Usage Plan1"  --api-stages  '[{ "apiId": "abcde12345", "stage":"test-stage", "throttle": {"POST /target": { "burstLimit": 200, "rateLimit": 100}}}]' --throttle burstLimit=200,rateLimit=100 --quota limit=500,offset=0,period=MONTH`  . The error is still related to the `apiId` - `no matches found: [apiId:abcde12345]` . Is that the REST API ID or the API Key ID or the Resource ID. The docs aren't clear about it

Comment: @Navidk This is a new issue. Your original problem and error were about using wrong key for method name. My answer correctly addresses the original problem that you reported. For the new problem, I would suggest making new question with relevant details and examples.